# Replace table with command in Crystal Reports XI

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I'm trying the replace a table with a command.

Replacing one table with another is usually no problem. Trying to do the same thing with a "command". It seems to work at first, an edit command window opens. I type in the command (I used "select * from myTable" as a test case), click ok and absolutely nothing happens.

Background is that the one table now contains multiple rows per serial num (which it didn't when the report was first created), and I need to aggregate that data. So, instead of creating groups in CR and changing every field in the whole report, I want aggregate the data in SQL and use the command instead of the table.
(Creating a view on the DB is not an option.)

Thanks
Martin

Comment: When you say "nothing happens" you mean the edited SQL Command just doesn't get saved but the window closes and returns you to the Database Expert like normal? Does it seem to validate/run the new Command query?

Comment: Yes, and no. The command editor closes and I'm back to database expert, with absolutely no visisble change. There's no delay after I click Ok, so there does not seem to be any validation happening either.

Comment: Whenever I hear "multiple rows per (anything)", I think of missing links between tables. Is there another table in your report? If you link the 2 together, that problem might disappear.

Comment: No, that's not the case. There are multiple relevant rows, and I do want to aggregate these rows (ie sums/averages on some fields).

Answer (score 0):

What does the SQL syntax look like when you are just using tables?  Possibly you could use that as a template for building your own SQL statement.

Answer (score -1):

Try and create a new report with your command instead of replacing the data source on an existing report.

I've had problems with that before.